# Python xlswriter setting format after writing a line

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

In the following loop I'm writting cells and formating some of them.
In some cases I'd like to set bg_color

```
def WriteExcelData(workbook,worksheet,row,datas):
col = 0
formatDate = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'dd/mm/yy'})
formatHour = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'hh:mm'})
for data in datas:
    if re.match('^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$', data):
        #print 'date:',data
        worksheet.write(row,col,datetime.strptime(data, '%d/%m/%Y'),formatDate)
    elif re.match('^\d{2}\:\d{2}\:\d{2}$', data):
        worksheet.write(row,col,datetime.strptime(data, '%H:%M:%S'),formatHour)
    else:
        worksheet.write(row,col,data)

    col += 1
return
```

Is there a way to apply a format on a line after it has been written ?
If not, is it possible to combine several format ?
something like :

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'hh:mm'})
format2 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#dcdcdc'})
format3 = format1 + format2
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
format1 = workbook.add_format({
            'num_format': 'hh:mm'
            'bg_color': '#dcdcdc'
            })
format2 = workbook.add_format({
            'num_format': 'hh:mm'
            })
```

- You can try this if you want to set num_formate and bg_colort than set format1 otherwise format2.

**OR** 
- May be this example will help you.

```
caption = ('Duplicate values are in light red. '
           'Unique values are in light green.')

worksheet3.write('A1', caption)

for row, row_data in enumerate(data):
    worksheet3.write_row(row + 2, 1, row_data)

worksheet3.conditional_format('B3:K12', {'type': 'duplicate','format': format1})
worksheet3.conditional_format('B3:K12', {'type': 'unique','format': format2})
```

Comment: This is unfortunately not the solution as the formatting will depend on the raw I'm writing. I'd like to pass a parameter to the initial function which would be added to existing format.

Comment: Now try this logic.

Comment: I use conditional_format in an other situation, but in this case it doesn't fit. As I said above it's on the entire line that I want to set the bg_color. The function write lines, and when comes a total or subtotal line I want to change the color

Comment: ohky, now i understand your problem. you already write one function but you want to set color in only sub total and total field.

Comment: Yes that's it. My solution is to store in memory all the dataframe adding some fields to caracterize special lines then to write to file.